# Issue with Load time PhpMailer (Execution)

Tags: email, phpmailer

I have a problem with phpmailer takes about 5 seconds to send 10 emails, I think that is a long time, because I need to send some 100 or 200 emails and the script takes too long and I get error 500.

Work with maybe 10 or 20 emails, but if i have more show error.

Need help please.

```
  Note: $email2 is array emails.
    require 'smtp/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                               // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = "localhost";  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'contacto@xxx.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'password';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true; // SMTP connection will not close after each email sent, reduces SMTP overhead
    $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->setFrom('contacto@xxx.com', 'Website');
    $mail->Subject = 'Se ha actualizado tu serie favorita';
    $mail->AltBody = 'Para ver este mensaje, use un visor de email compatible con HTML!';
    $mail->addReplyTo('contacto@xxx.com');
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Body = 'The Body is HTML Code';
    if($vtitle == "Existe") {
    foreach($email2 as $email3)
    {
    $mail2 = clone $mail;
    $mail2->addAddress(''.$email3.'');     // Add a recipient
    $envio = $mail2->send();
    }
    } else {
        echo "El Capitulo no Existe";   
    }
    if(!$envio) {
        echo 'El Mensaje no ha podido enviarse.';
        echo 'Error: ' . $mail2->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'El Mensaje ha sido enviado.';
    }
```

If I change SMTPAuth to False for not authentication is the same problem.

Comment: My 2 cents: Don’t try to set up your own mass mailer – use a service provider that knows what they’re doing, like mailchimp, cleverreach, etc.

Comment: Yes, SMTP is slow. The main thing is don't try to send lots of mail during a page submission. Set up what you want to do in a database and use a cron job or a long-running process to send the messages.